# MongoDB | update two fields with different data

Tags: mongodb

I am working on a mongodb database named booksdb with collection name books

Fields

`[{ "_id" : 19, "title":"A"}, { "_id" : 21, "title":"B"}]`

I have to add a comments array to book ids 19 and  21 for each book together in one update command

PS: Sorry I solved this i missed filter and update command! I posted my solution, However, Better solutions are welcomed Thank you!
[image]

I thought of bulkWrite()

```
try{db.books.bulkWrite([{updateOne: {{"_id":19},{$set:{"comments":[{"Name":"Joe","Content":"nice book. Practice questions are helpful","rating": 5},{"Name": "David","Content": "excellent book. Contains illustratives","rating": 4}]}}}},{updateOne:{{"_id":21},{$set:{"comments":[{"Name": "Joe","Content": "nice book.","rating": 4},{"Name": "Sam","Content": "excellent book. Contains illustratives","rating": 5}}]}}}])}catch(e){print(e);}
```

But this gave error, can anyone help! Thank You

Comment: Sorry I solved this i missed filter and update command! I posted my solution

Comment: Better solutions are welcomed Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try{
db.books.bulkWrite([
{ updateOne : {
    "filter" : {"_id":19},
    "update" : { $set : { "commetns" : [{"Name":"Joe","Content":"nice book. Practice questions are helpful","rating": 5},{"Name": "David","Content": "excellent book. Contains illustratives","rating": 4}] } }
 } },
 { updateOne : {
    "filter" : {"_id":21},
    "update" : { $set : { "commetns" : [{"Name": "Joe","Content": "nice book.","rating": 4},
        {"Name": "Sam","Content": "excellent book. Contains illustratives","rating": 5}] } }
 } }
 ])}catch(e){
     print(e);
    }
```